# Pygame Not Loading Images Correctly

Tags: python, pygame, opensuse

The way that I load images into my projects work on the Windows machines at my school, but when I came home and wrote some code in the same format on OpenSUSE, my image isn't loading properly.

```
import pygame
import os

pygame.init()

os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER']='windib'

class game(object):

def __init__(self):
    self._running = True
    self._screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
    self._background = pygame.Surface(self._screen.get_size())
    self._background.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.display.set_caption('The Spice is Right')
    self.scroller1 = pygame.image.load("scroller.png")
    self.scroller2 = pygame.image.load("scroller.png")
    self.playerCross = pygame.image.load("")
    self.playerRect = self.playerCross.get_rect()
    self.head = pygame.image.load("tyler.png")
    self.headRect = self.head.get_rect()
    self.title = pygame.image.load("spiceMain.png")
    self.timer = 100
    self.attack = False
    self.spiceLevel = 0

    self.headRight = False
    self.headLeft = False
    self.headUp = False
    self.headDown = False

    self.titleScreen = True
    self.gameMode = False
    self.bgy = 0
    self.bgy2 = -600

def run(self):
    while self._running:
        self.handle_input()
        pygame.display.flip()
        self.bgMethod()
        if self.titleScreen:
            self.backgrounScroll()
        if self.gameMode:
            self.bgMethod()
            self.headMethod()
            self.player()

    pygame.quit()
def handle_input(self):
    for evt in pygame.event.get():
        if evt.type == pygame.QUIT:
            self._running = False
        elif evt.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if evt.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                self._running = False
def bgMethod(self):
    self._screen.blit(self._background,(0,0))

def backgroundScroll(self):
    self._screen.blit(self.scroller1,(0,self.bgy))
    self._screen.blit(self.scroller2,(0,self.bgy2))
    self._screen.blit(self.title,(400,300))
    self.bgy += 4
    self.bgy += 4
    if self.bgy >= 600:
        self.bgy == 0
    if self.bgy2 >= 600:
        self.bgy2 == 0
def headMethod(self):
    self._screen.blit(self.head(self.headRect.x,self.headRect.y))
    if self.headRect.x <= 800:
        self.headRight = True
    if self.headRect.x >= 800:
        self.headLeft = True
    if self.headRect.x <= 0:
        self.headRight = True
    if self.headRect.x >= 0:
        self.headLeft = True

    if self.headRight:
        self.headRect.x += 6
    if self.headLeft:
        self.headRect.x -= 6

    if self.headRect.y <= 600:
        self.headDown
    if self.headRect.y >= 600:
        self.headUp
    if self.headRect.y <= 0:
        self.headDown
    if self.headRect.y >= 0:
        self.headUp

    if self.headUp:
        self.rectHead.y -= 6
    if self.headDown:
        self.rectHead.y  += 6
def player(self):
    self._screen.blit(self.playerCross,(pygame.mouse.get_pos()))
def attackMethod(self):
    if self.timer == 100:
        if self.attack:
            self.timer == 0
            self.timer += 1
            if self.timer == 100:
                self.spiceLevel += 1



g= game()
g.run
```

And no, I have not yet been able to test this code on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

```
os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER']='windib'
```

Delete this line.

`SDL_VIDEODRIVER` isn't really needed unless you are doing something weird. As you can see from [this site](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_envvars), `windib` refers to `Win95/98/NT/2000 GDI (Win32)`... obviously not something available on OpenSUSE. SDL (and hence pygame) should have sensible defaults and choose the right video driver for the platform, so there is no need to set this envvar.

Comment: I totally forgot, it's a required line to work on our Windows machines at the school, thank you for the help, I will test this when I get home